# OpenGL, texturing a simple sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, textures, glsl

i'm trying to texture a sphere with OpenGL programmable pipeline and dont know what goes wrong here.

Initialization:

```
earth = createSphere(1, 64, 32);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
earthTex = createTexture("textures/earth.jpg");
```

createTexture:

```
GLuint createTexture(const char* fileName)
{
    GLuint texID;
    int width, height, imgFormat, internalFormat;
    float* imgData = getImage(fileName, &height, &width, &imgFormat);
    switch (imgFormat)
    {
    case GL_RED: internalFormat = GL_R8; break;
    case GL_RG: internalFormat = GL_RG8; break;
    case GL_RGB: internalFormat = GL_RGB8; break;
    case GL_RGBA: internalFormat = GL_RGBA8; break;
    default: fprintf(stderr, "\n Cannot get ImgType \n"); break;
    }
    glGenTextures(1, &texID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, width, height, 0, imgFormat, GL_FLOAT, (void*) imgData);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return texID;
}
```

RenderLoop:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, earthTex);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "colorTex"), 0);
earth->draw();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

In vertexShader I'm passing texCoords to FragmentShader and there i just call something like `fs_out_color = texture(colorTex, fs_in_texCoords);`
where colorTex is uniform sampler2D. 
As soon as I comment this out, everything works fine (except vertex coloring obviously). 
Anyone got a a clue?
Thanks!

Edit:
Thats my FragmentShader. As you can see, nothing too special.

```
#version 150 core

uniform sampler2D colorTex;
in vec3 fs_in_color;
in vec2 fs_in_texCoods;
out vec4 fs_out_color;

void main(void) {
    fs_out_color = texture(colorTex, fs_in_texCoords);
}
```

Edit2: If I change fs_out_color to  fs_in_color (which are currently normals), everything works fine. Otherwise OpenGL states INVALID_OPERATION after drawElements call.

Comment: Can you add your fragment shader? (And: consider using the `GL_KHR_debug` extension to get valuable debug output from GL).

Comment: Your `getImage (...)` function actually returns floating-point pixels? That seems awfully wasteful, even if you were loading HDR image formats, you are ultimately going to store it in an 8-bit fixed-point texture. It seems particularly wasteful since you appear to be leaking memory every time you call that function.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will fix that, but this shouldnt solve my problem.